# I changed the font for the main text but I didn't change the table font - nevertheless the table looks different

Tags: fonts

I experimented with palatino and Cambria for the main text but the table font (sffamily) got another look also. I prefer the look that goes with palatino. See the two images.
Here is the code.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper] {report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{palatino}
\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{Cambria-Font-For-Windows}{m}{n} #1 }}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{18}{22}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{14}{17}}
\newcommand{\subsecfnt}{\fontsize{11}{13}}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\subsecfnt\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=4cm, right=2.5cm, top=1.8cm, bottom=2.5cm, textheight=18cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{10pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.01em}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

\newcommand\setrow[1]{\gdef\rowmac{#1}#1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\clearrow{\global\let\rowmac\relax}
\clearrow

\begin{document}
In deze bijlage staan de verslagen van de interviews die in januari 2008 uitgevoerd zijn. In de volgende tabel staat welke personen geïnterviewd zijn.

\vspace{13pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\fontsize{8.5pt}{10pt}
\sffamily
\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{\rowmac} m{3cm} >{\rowmac} m{0.4cm} >{\rowmac} m{2.5cm} >{\rowmac} m{0.4cm} >{\rowmac} m{4cm} >{\rowmac} m{0.4cm} >{\rowmac} m{2cm} <{\clearrow}} 
\setrow{\bfseries\itshape} naam && afdeling && functie &&  datum \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-3} \cline{5-5} \cline{7-7}
Jan de Vries & &  Verkoop & &  manager & &  09-01-2008 \\
Peter Jansen & & Inkoop & & senior inkoper & & 10-01-2008 \\
Ingrid Holtrup && Public relations && teamleider && 14-01-2008 \\
Patrick Faber && Personeelszaken && administratief medewerker && 15-01-2008
\end{tabular}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
\normalfont \normalsize

\vspace{13pt}
\subsection*{Interview met Jan de Vries}
Jan de Vries maakte duidelijk dat het belangrijk is ...
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Erh, `palatino` also changes the sans serif font. Most of these packages do, here is the contents of the `palatino` package: `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
`

Answer (score 6):

You should not use `palatino`, which is obsolete and deprecated.

It also changes the sans serif font. Do `\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}` instead, which doesn't touch the other font families.

The code has been massaged, separating package loading from settings.

I also removed altogether the `\setrow` business, because I find it much easier and less invasive to use a simple macro for each head item.

The spaces between columns are more easily obtained with `booktabs` and `\cmidrule`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper] {report}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}% <--- not palatino
\usepackage{fix-cm} % for CM fonts in nonstandard sizes
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% geometry
\geometry{
  left=4cm,
  right=2.5cm,
  top=1.8cm,
  bottom=2.5cm,
  heightrounded,% <-- to ensure a whole number of lines
%  textheight=18cm, %%% <--- you can't specify both top/bottom and textheight
}

%% titles
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\secfnt\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\subsecfnt\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

%% personal commands
\newcommand{\HD}[1]{#1} % default
\newcommand{\formathead}[1]{\renewcommand{\HD}[1]{#1##1}}

\newcommand{\chapfnt}{\fontsize{18}{22}}
\newcommand{\secfnt}{\fontsize{14}{17}}
\newcommand{\subsecfnt}{\fontsize{11}{13}}
%%% I don't have it
%\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{Cambria-Font-For-Windows}{m}{n} #1 }}
%%% another that can be easily recognized
\newcommand\customfont[1]{{\usefont{T1}{OldStandard-TLF}{m}{n}#1}}% <--- no spaces!

%% various settings
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{10pt}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.01em}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1} 
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} % <---- really?


\begin{document}
In deze bijlage staan de verslagen van de interviews die in januari 2008 
uitgevoerd zijn. In de volgende tabel staat welke personen geïnterviewd zijn.

\vspace{13pt}\begingroup
\fontsize{8.5pt}{10pt}\sffamily
\formathead{\bfseries\itshape}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  w{l}{3cm}
  w{l}{2.5cm}
  w{l}{4cm}
  w{l}{2cm}
  @{}
}
\HD{naam}      & \HD{afdeling}    & \HD{functie}              & \HD{datum} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
\cmidrule(l){4-4}
Jan de Vries   & Verkoop          & manager                   & 09-01-2008 \\
Peter Jansen   & Inkoop           & senior inkoper            & 10-01-2008 \\
Ingrid Holtrup & Public relations & teamleider                & 14-01-2008 \\
Patrick Faber  & Personeelszaken  & administratief medewerker & 15-01-2008
\end{tabular}
\par\endgroup\vspace{13pt}

\subsection*{Interview met Jan de Vries}
Jan de Vries maakte duidelijk dat het belangrijk is ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: egreg: thanks a lot for these improvements and daleif: ty for that useful information